# Nested Sum Encountered in Maclaurin Expansion of $e^{-x^2}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, examples-counterexamples, products

In the course of working out the Maclaurin expansions of $e^{-x^2}$ and $cos(x^2)$, I ran into the following nested sum:

$$ \underbrace{ \sum_{a=0}^1 \left( a \sum_{b=0}^{a+1} b \left( \sum_{c=0}^{b+1} c \cdots d \sum_{e=0}^{d+1} \left( e \sum_{f=0}^{e+1} f \right) \right) \right) }_{\text{n sums deep}} $$

To illustrate, for $n=4$ the above will expand to

$$ 1(2(3(4+3+2+1)+2(3+2+1)+1(2+1))+1(2(3+2+1)+1(2+1))) $$

Then from looking at a hand calculation of the first few terms and guessing the pattern, it looks like the above should be equal to

$$ \prod_{k=1}^n (2k-1) $$

Indeed, I numerically confirmed equality up to $n=16$, but haven't had luck at finding a proof yet.

Can you find either a proof or a counterexample?

Comment: Where do a,b,c,d,e and f come from?

Comment: @user166967, they are just indices of the respective sums.

Answer (score 2):

Define $a(n,1)=n(1+2+\dots+(n+1))=n(n+1)(n+2)/2$. Then define recursively $$a(n,k)=n\sum_{r=1}^{n+1}a(r,k-1)$$ Then your sequence is $a(1,1),a(1,2),a(1,3),\dots$. So entering that into Mathematica, we get $3, 15, 105, 945, 10395, 135135,\dots$. Checking with oeis.org we find these are just the numbers $1\times3\times5\times7\times\dots\times 2n-1$.

Since you did not ask for a proof of the correct formula and I am lazy, I have not given one, but it should be fairly easy by induction.

Comment: Thank you. The recursive definition you reformulated the sum into is quite nice. I don't, however, see the 'easy induction' proof. Would you mind suppressing the laziness urge providing a little more in the way of proof? :) Also edited question to more clearly state desire of proof.

Comment: almagest, your reformulation inspired me and I finally figured it out! See the answer I posted if you want to see the nitty-gritty details. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Returned to the problem and things became clear. Thank you to [almagest](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/172006/almagest) for the inspiration to consider his recursive function.

To keep everything in one spot, I'll start from the beginning defintions:

Let $S \colon \mathbb{N}^{2} \to \mathbb{N}$ and define as follows:

$$ \begin{align}
S(0,0) & \equiv 0 \\
S(0,k) & \equiv 0 \\
S(a,0) & \equiv 1 \label{eq_Sa0}\tag{1}\\
S(a,k) & \equiv \sum_{n_{1}=0}^{a} n_{1} \sum_{n_{2}=0}^{n_{1}+1} + ... n_{k-1} \sum_{n_k=0}^{n_{k-1}+1}
\end{align} $$

Then we can recursively define $S$ as follows:

$$ S(a,k+1) = \sum_{n=0}^{a} n S(n+1,k) $$

We wish to show the following since the case $a=1$ reduces to my original question (to be shown below):

$$
S(a,k) = \frac{1}{2^{k}k!} \prod_{p=0}^{2k-1} (a+p) 
\label{eq_main}\tag{2} $$

Before we continue we will need to make use of the following lemma (pay close attention to the index $k$):

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{a} \prod_{p=0}^{k-1} (a+p) = \frac{1}{k+1} \prod_{p=0}^{k} (a+p) \label{eq_lemma}\tag{3} $$

To prove \ref{eq_lemma} we will proceed by induction. First notice that \ref{eq_lemma} is trivially true for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ when $a=0$:

$$ \begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{0} \prod_{p=0}^{k-1} (a+p) & = \prod_{p=0}^{k-1} p = 0 \\
& = \frac{1}{k+1} \prod_{p=0}^{k} (0+p)
\end{align} $$

Since we know know \ref{eq_lemma} is true for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ with at least some given $a \in \mathbb{N}$ then

$$ \begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{a+1} \prod_{p=0}^{k-1} (a+p) & = \sum_{n=0}^{a} \prod_{p=0}^{k-1} (a+p) + (a+1)(a+2) \cdots (a+k) \\
   & = \frac{1}{k+1} \prod_{p=0}^{k} (a+p) + (a+1)(a+2) \cdots (a+k) \\
   & = (a+1)(a+2) \cdots (a+k)\left(\frac{a}{k+1} + 1\right) \\
   & = \frac{1}{k+1}(a+1)(a+2) \cdots (a+k)[a + (k+1)] \\
   & = \frac{1}{k+1} \prod_{p=0}^{k} (a + 1 +p)
\end{align} $$

Thus *quod erat demonstrandum* for Lemma \ref{eq_lemma}.

Now let's return to proving \ref{eq_main} and proceed inductively from the trivial case $k=1$ which is clearly true for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ since by definition we know \ref{eq_Sa0}:

$$ \begin{align}
S(a,1) & = \sum_{n=0}^{a} n S(a+1,0) \\ 
       & = \sum_{n=0}^{a} n \\
       & = \frac{1}{2} a(a+1)
\end{align} $$

Thus we know that \ref{eq_main} is true for all $a \in \mathbb{N}$ for some particular $k \in \mathbb{N}$. So we proceed by induction on $k$, keeping in mind Lemma \ref{eq_lemma} from above:

$$ \begin{align}
S(a,k+1) & = \sum_{n=0}^{a} n S(n+1,k) \\
         & = \sum_{n=0}^{a} n \frac{1}{2^{k}k!} \prod_{p=0}^{2k-1} (n + 1 +p) \\
         & = \frac{1}{2^{k}k!} \sum_{n=0}^{a}  \prod_{p=0}^{2k} (n + p) \\
         & = \frac{1}{2^{k}k!} \left[\frac{1}{2(k+1)} \prod_{p=0}^{k+1} (a+p)\right] \\
         & = \frac{1}{2^{k+1}(k+1)!} \prod_{p=0}^{k+1} (a+p)
\end{align} $$

And Q.E.D. for equation \ref{eq_main}. Now all the remains to be shown is that \ref{eq_main} reduces to the question in the original post when $a=1$:

$$ \begin{align}
\sum_{n_{1}=0}^{1} n_{1} \sum_{n_{2}=0}^{n_{1}+1} + ... n_{k-1} \sum_{n_k=0}^{n_{k-1}+1} &= S(1,k) \\
       & = \frac{1}{2^{k}k!} \prod_{p=0}^{2k-1} (p+1) \\
       & = \frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots (2k-1)2k}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots (2k-2)2k} \\
       & = \prod_{p=1}^{k} (2p-1)
\end{align} $$

Q.E.D.

Thanks again, [almagest](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/172006/almagest), for the inspiration!